# What are the benefits of R6RS Scheme's make-variable-transformer?

Tags: macros, scheme

While looking at the `syntax-case` section in R6RS, I saw the keyword `make-variable-transformer`, described as an *identifier macro*. The example given is very minimal, and I am not groking why it is necessary, or what use-cases require it. Finding additional examples of its use is also proving difficult. Presumably it makes some form of syntax transformation possible, or more elegant?

Answer (score 2):

After reading http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-13.html#node_sec_12.3 my take is as follows:

If `mac` is a syntax transformer

`(mac foo (bar baz))` would replace the entire s-expr with the result of the transformation this could result in anything say `(SOMETHING)`, while `(foo mac bar)` would replace only `mac` resulting in `(foo SOMETHING bar)`.

Normally `(set! mac 'foo)` would signal an error it seems that the transformer can not appear on the left of a set expression, but if `mac` is a variable transformer `(set! mac 'foo)` would instead call `mac` with the whole s-expr.

My intuition tells me this would be useful if you start implementing datatypes with macros.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this searching for documentation on make-variable-transformer.  Here's a problem I had that make-variable-transformer was suggested for...

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.scheme/browse_frm/thread/96b07d431f1a66de/777f8e07ae1855f3#777f8e07ae1855f3

Jack Trades